# Who do I call to pick up my IFR Clearance at KBKL?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules

I've had my IFR rating for ~2 years now, but haven't done much other than practice approaches to stay current. Flying to KBKL tomorrow, and when I depart to come back, I can't tell who I call to pick up my clearance.

The approach plates say "CLNC DEL 121.9 (when tower closed)" - okay, what about when the tower is open?

I've tried googling around, but the internet is filled with people asking how to pick up clearances in the air; I trained at a non-towered field so I've got the opposite issue.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a link: http://airnav.com/airport/KBKL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When there is no separate Clearance Delivery frequency, just call on the ground control frequency to get your clearance.

Separate Clearance Delivery frequencies are only needed at busy airports to relieve radio congestion and work load.

Even at a "busy" airport sometimes you will see(hear) one controller work both Ground and Clnc Del when the workload is low.

Comment: In this case the frequency is the same regardless of when you use it or who you talk to. Ground-point-nine to talk to Lakefront Ground when they are open, or Cleveland Approach otherwise.

Comment: @JWalters precisely. When the tower is open, 121.9 is used by Lakefront Ground (who is also the clearance delivery controller)—there is no clearance delivery frequency when the  tower is open. When the tower is closed, 121.9 is used by Cleveland [Approach] Clearance Delivery—there is no ground controller. Different airports may do it differently, for example at an airport where the tower **and** approach are closed overnight, clearance delivery might be the overlying ARTCC on the (daytime) approach control frequency.